# Is it possible to hide the Google Places API error box when there is an API key error?

Tags: angular, google-places-api, api-key, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

Currently, we are having some billing information with the account associated with the API key we are using. We currently want to be able to hide the google places API dropdown whenever there are payment/API key failures/errors.

This is an Angular application and we are using `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` any help or way to detect the error programmatically would be beneficial so that we can dynamically apply a CSS class or something.

How do I catch this error(any Google API related error) programmatically and do some logic afterwards:

[image: Google payment console error]

[image: google payment error]

Answer (score 1):

[window.gm_authFailure](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors) will be called if there is an auth error.

> If you want to programmatically detect an authentication failure (for example to automatically send an beacon) you can prepare a callback function. If the following global function is defined it will be called when the authentication fails.

```js
window.gm_authFailure = () => {
  // set flag, css class, etc
}
```

See related in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gm_authfailure.